# Change background color of Editable row in Primeng datatable

Tags: primeng, angular9

I am using CRUD operation on Primeng Datatable. If i clicked row of the table it raises the dialog box to edit the data. But selected row's background changed to blue. Is there any way to change background color of selected row? Primeng version 9.1.1
i referred [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537505/primeng-datatable-row-selection-change-color) But not working.

Comment: can you add some relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`:host p-table ::ng-deep .ui-state-highlight{ background:red; }`

**Explain**

After `:host` you have to set the component that host in your component (in your case the Primeng table)

And then after `::ng-deep` set the class that inside the hosted component that you want to change

[for example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-zvj9ui?file=app%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.css)

**EDIT**

to make it more generic you can put the code in `style.css` file as below

`p-table .ui-state-highlight{ background:red!important; }`

[see example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-d5k5n9?file=styles.css)

Comment: this  will work but this for single component inn case you have the table in another component you have to copy the style to that component style 

Comment: merhaba ! In this case we put the code in the `style.css` (the shared css) without the `host` and without the `ng-deep`

Comment: iyi günler :) :)